# Images comes in to the screen when scrolling

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, scroll, slide

Is there any plugin who can do that? When you are scrolling down the images will show up and slide from left or right to the center. I have searched and i couldn't find it. So does anybody know a plugin?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want something like the [**lazyLoad plugin**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) with [**effects**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html).

Check out this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pdWqR/20).

I just added a custom effect, like the one you described and bound it to the `effect` property on the `lazyLoad` initiation.

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.extend({
      slideInLeft: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).show().css({opacity: 0, position: 'relative', left: "-200px"});
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1, left: 0}, 'slow');
        });
      }
    });

    $("img").show().lazyload({
        'effect': 'slideInLeft'
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah thats what i mean! Great! but when you scroll up again the images stays on the same place but is there an option when you scroll up again the images go to the left again?

Comment: @RidvanDuman Not that I'm aware of. In that case you would have to add that logic when scrolling.

Comment: thanks for your help i will work with the code!

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/LateralOnScrollSliding/ look on this project thats some cool coding! Wanted to achieve something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
var SCROLLPOSITION = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function (){
     var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop() + SCROLLPOSITION;
     scrollpos = Math.floor(scrollpos/3);
     $('#oke').css("left", scrollpos + 'px');  //divname of moving image
     SCROLLPOSITION = $(this).scrollTop();
});
```

btw wont work correctly in chrome, ie etc (cuz of their multiple line skipping on mousewheel)

-works for Firefox

Edited (and updated on js fiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/gQTAy/6/

works now

**ok nvm... misunderstood question**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gQTAy/1/ i dont get it to work.